# Error: Process started but the activation request failed with error 'The app didn't start' when using external debugger

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, uwp

I am trying to use an external tool called [Deleaker](https://www.deleaker.com/) so I can monitor my application, but this does not seem to work with UWP applications. I'm wondering if there is a setting in the configuration somewhere that allows me to bypass, or fix this activation issue as I'm sure it's to do with the Deleaker process attaching to the UWP application.

I only get this issue when I try to debug with Deleaker enabled through Visual Studio. It is fine when Deleaker is disabled. I have also tried running it outside Visual Studio without the tool and it does not open properly. Running it outside of Visual Studio through Deleaker seems to give me an error `Unhandled exception at 0x00007ff613d0ba79`, but upon terminating the process, it does give me some output to suggest the application loaded.

Does anyone have any ideas how I can solve these issues?

Comment: Why don't you ask the vendor?

Comment: @UweKeim I have sent an email, but I thought someone might have ran into the same issue. Can't seem to find anything on SO related to this though.